# What does the phrase "slide into first" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

I heard a phrase "slide into first" in an arcade racing game's description. This was used as the introductory sentence that was followed by speed boosting and drifting tips.

I know the lexical meanings of the word "slide", but none of them seems to fit here.

Comment: First gear perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is less about English than racing terminology.  It helps if you understand *drag* (friction caused by the flow of air around the car) and how [*drafting*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BeGFqBVX2c) (riding closely behind another car) reduces this drag.

"First" in this case refers to "First Place".  If you draft behind the lead car you can use the temporary reduced drag to slip around at the last moment and "slide" into first place, winning the race.  Apparently this is fairly complicated in the real world (not to mention dangerous) but in an arcade game the real-world aerodynamics are simplified to make the game more enjoyable.